# Delayed upload to OneDrive

Tags: onedrive

I created a web service which consists of a server part and a client part. The server part generates a file which should be saved automatically to onedrive. The size of the file is quite large and it`s content changes frequently. (Which prevents me from saving the file after each modification.)

I checked the onedrive api and currently see the following two solutions:

1. Authenticate the client via the „token flow“. In this case, the
   problem is that there is (as far as I know) no reliable solution
   which can trigger the upload to onedrive before the browser is
   closed. (Should work on dekstop, iOS,…)
2. Authenticate the server via the „code flow“. In this case the server has the ability to save the file to onedrive even if the browser was already closed. The problem is, that the server has to keep a record of all authenticate users and their long term refresh tokens. Which could be a huge security risk, I would like to avoid.

Are there any other solutions to this problem?

Comment: What other option would you want to have? "Code flow" is the standard way for doing what you're looking for.

Comment: I would like to have a option, which reduces the security risk for the end user as much as possible.

Comment: Is this for OneDrive Personal or OneDrive for Business?

Comment: It should work with both.